# To clear old alarm from Things board which has not come for a long duration

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

My requirement is to query the DB and publish locations of temperature that has crossed a particular threshold. So I am directly select and send only the device details, which has crossed a particular threshold  via MQTT , so that it reflects them as alarm.

It indeed reflects. Now let me say I have 5 devices A,B,C,D,E and I send alerts for A,C,E which has the temperature crossed beyond a threshold limit, it reflects the data in Thingsboard dashboard.

After a minute, I push A,C,D where E has now come under control, hence it need not reflect it on the alarm. But what I see is A,C,D,E on the screen. How can I clear the alarm for E as it has not come as a part of the new message set that I have pushed to MQTT.

I use community edition. Also I have professional one if I have to test that.

Kindly suggest